# SEO: same physical file (URL) at different webpages

Tags: seo, google-image-search, image-search

Let me take an example of what I mentioned in the title, I have a image of dinning room with a nice table, good chairs, which is stored at `http://example.com/static/the-dinning-room.jpg`, uploaded by user A in collection "*A's dinning room*". Then user B came, liked the chairs, the decided to add the pic to his "*Nice chairs*" collection. Likewise, user C added the pic to his "*My favorite tables*". Each of them also have new title and description of that very same image.

I definitely don't want to duplicate the file (for many good reasons), but I don't know which one to put to [Google image site map](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636) . How do I let google know that pic is about dinning room , chairs and table at the same time. Can I just concatenate the title and description from A, B and C ??!!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use different filenames for each image on each page and in each image itself, make slight modifications to emphasize each section of the dining room such as adding text in the image indicating to the user what is being emphasized.

For example, on site A, you'd have the image file `http://example.com/static/dining-room.jpg` with the word "dining room" in the picture, and on site B, you'd have the image file `http://example.com/static/nice-chairs.jpg` with the word "nice chairs" in the picture and on site C, you'd have the image file `http://example.com/static/favorite-tables.jpg` with the word "favouritism tables" in the picture.

You will then be able to submit all files to a sitemap since nothing is then duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Mike's answer above is nice and I would follow it myself. However if you really need to reuse the file (save storage, better cache, etc. ) you could concatenate the title and description in sitemap to the limit size that Google recommends. Since you have the pages (with related text or comments  from members) to backup your images, it would be legit to SEO